# Synchronization mechanism for an observable object

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-synchronization

Let's imagine we have to synchronize read/write access to shared resources. Multiple threads will access that resource both in read and writing (most of times for reading, sometimes for writing). Let's assume also that each write will always trigger a read operation (object is observable).

For this example I'll imagine a class like this (forgive syntax and style, it's just for illustration purposes):

```
class Container {
    public ObservableCollection<Operand> Operands;
    public ObservableCollection<Result> Results;
}
```

I'm tempted to use a `ReadWriterLockSlim` for this purpose moreover I'd put it at `Container` level (imagine object is not so simple and one read/write operation may involve multiple objects):

```
public ReadWriterLockSlim Lock;
```

Implementation of `Operand` and `Result` has no meaning for this example.
Now let's imagine some code that observes `Operands` and will produce a result to put in `Results`:

```
void AddNewOperand(Operand operand) {
    try {
        _container.Lock.EnterWriteLock();
        _container.Operands.Add(operand);
    }
    finally {
        _container.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
```

Our hypotetical observer will do something similar but to consume a new element and it'll lock with `EnterReadLock()` to get operands and then `EnterWriteLock()` to add result (let me omit code for this). This will produce an exception because of recursion but if I set `LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion` then I'll just open my code to dead-locks (from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

> By default, new instances of ReaderWriterLockSlim are created with the LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion flag and do not allow recursion. This default policy is recommended for all new development, because **recursion** introduces unnecessary complications and **makes your code more prone to deadlocks**.

I repeat relevant part for clarity:

**Recursion [...] makes your code more prone to deadlocks.**

If I'm not wrong with `LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion` if from same thread I ask a, let's say, read lock then *someone* else asks for a write lock then I'll have a dead-lock then what MSDN says makes sense. Moreover recursion will degrade performance too in a measurable way (and it's not what I want if I'm using `ReadWriterLockSlim` instead of `ReadWriterLock` or `Monitor`).

### Question(s)

Finally my questions are (please note I'm not searching for a discussion about general synchronization mechanisms, I would know what's wrong for **this producer/observable/observer scenario**):

- What's better in this situation? To avoid `ReadWriterLockSlim` in favor of `Monitor` (even if in real world code reads will be much more than writes)?
- Give up with such coarse synchronization? This may even yield better performance but it'll make code much more complicated (of course not in this example but in real world).
- Should I just make notifications (from observed collection) asynchronous?
- Something else I can't see?

I know that there is not a *best* synchronization mechanism so *tool* we use must be right one for our case but I wonder if there are some best practice or I just ignore something very important between threads and observers (imagine to use [Microsoft Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) but question is general, not tied to that framework).

### Possible solutions?

What I would try is to make events (somehow) deferred:

**1st solution**
Each change won't fire any `CollectionChanged` event, it's kept in a queue. When provider (object that push data) has finished it'll manually force the queue to be flushed (raising each event in sequence). This may be done in another thread or even in the caller thread (but outside the lock).

It may works but it'll make everything less "automatic" (each change notification must be manually triggered by producer itself, more code to write, more bugs all around).

**2nd solution**
Another solution may be to provide a reference to our *lock* to the observable collection. If I wrap `ReadWriterLockSlim` in a custom object (useful to hide it in a easy to use `IDisposable` object) I may add a `ManualResetEvent` to notify that all locks has been released in this way collection itself may rise events (again in the same thread or in another thread).

**3rd solution**
Another idea could be to just make events asynchronous. If event handler will need a lock then it'll be stopped to wait it's time frame. For this I worry about the big thread amount that may be used (especially if from thread pool).

Honestly I don't know if any of these is applicable in real world application (personally - from users point of view - I prefer second one but it implies custom collection for everything and it makes collection aware of threading and I would avoid it, if possible). I wouldn't like to make code more complicated than necessary.

Comment: I just want to mention that I find the `EnterReadLock` and `Add` combination quite scary. The code makes intention to only read, but instead it also writes to the collection. Are you sure you don't want to use `EnterWriteLock` at that specific point?

Comment: @Caramiriel you're right, I fixed example!

Comment: If you make your methods a little coarser, e.g. make Operands and Result read-only properties and add AddOperand and AddResult methods, you will be able to make the Lock private and stay more in control of what happens. Or am I completely missing the point?

Comment: @flup you're on the point. My _problem_ is that it'll make everything more complicated and model will be aware of threading (I would avoid this, if possible, because it'll hit performance when it'll be used in a single thread scenario). Moreover model itself is, of course, much more complicated than my example. Maybe a **thread-safe layer** built over model with methods like what you suggested?

Comment: Can't you use ConcurrentQueue and/or BlockingCollection? ObservableCollections are used for the situations where you somehow need to work with the whole collection, but if you're just adding new result when new operand is added, that sounds like a stream-based operation.
Or, alternatively, what about using a collection of operand-result paird? Again you could use some sort of existing Concurrent- collection class perhaps and would be free of all these problems.

Comment: @Tar I can't because this is a very simple example, in general it's not always true (I mean in my scenario) that observers will be blocked until something will happen. Imagine, just for example, UI that will update its data according to a change in model (triggered maybe from UI, maybe from an external source in another thread). Moreover observed object may not be a collection (an IObservable object may trigger events when a property changed).

Comment: Ok in that case I'd go with 3rd solution - firing the events asynchronously. I wouldn't worry about thread number. The times when this mattered are largely in the past.

Comment: @Tar probably you're right, I just did wonder if there may be drawbacks on that (I don't think, at least in my case, there will be a lot of running threads but some of them may take pretty long time and I worry to use thread pool for that). 3rd solution is easiest to implement so probably it'll be first one I'll try.

Comment: When I have done similar things in the past, I have implemented your 1st option. The reason being that 95% of the time, I find we are updating a moderate to large number of records (20+) in rapid succession. When this occurs, the observable is firing off events like no tomorrow and everything slows down to a crawl. Allowing for bulk operations, then firing the observable has always led to the best performance.

Comment: @Keith you're right about performance. So far I managed that adding two methods: BeginUpdate()/EndUpdate(). If multiple changes have been queued I fire a Reset event for CollectionChanged (or a custom Changed event instead of PropertyChanged for non-collection objects). Well, actually I may move EndUpdate() outside "lock" but I still hope I can manage that without too much trouble for model's users (well at least now I collected 1 vote per 1st solution and 1 vote for 3rd one, people...go on voting!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like quite the multi-threading pickle. It's quite challenging to work with recursion in this chain-of-events pattern, whilst still avoiding deadlocks. You might want to consider designing around the problem entirely.

For example, you could make the addition of an operand asynchronous to the raising of the event:

```
private readonly BlockingCollection<Operand> _additions
    = new BlockingCollection<Operand>();

public void AddNewOperand(Operand operand)
{
    _additions.Add(operand);
}
```

And then have the actual addition happen in a background thread:

```
private void ProcessAdditions()
{
    foreach(var operand in _additions.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        _container.Lock.EnterWriteLock();
        _container.Operands.Add(operand);
        _container.Lock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}

public void Initialize()
{
    var pump = new Thread(ProcessAdditions)
    {
        Name = "Operand Additions Pump"
    };
    pump.Start();
}
```

This separation sacrifices some consistency - code running after the add method won't actually know when the add has actually happened and maybe that's a problem for your code. If so, this could be re-written to subscribe to the observation and use a `Task` to signal when the add completes:

```
public Task AddNewOperandAsync(Operand operand)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<byte>();

    // Compose an event handler for the completion of this task
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler onChanged = null;
    onChanged = (sender, e) =>
    {
        // Is this the event for the operand we have added?
        if (e.NewItems.Contains(operand))
        {
            // Complete the task.
            tcs.SetCompleted(0);

            // Remove the event-handler.
            _container.Operands.CollectionChanged -= onChanged;
        }
    }

    // Hook in the handler.
    _container.Operands.CollectionChanged += onChanged;

    // Perform the addition.
    _additions.Add(operand);

    // Return the task to be awaited.
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

The event-handler logic is raised on the background thread pumping the add messages, so there is no possibility of it blocking your foreground threads. If you await the add on the message-pump for the window, the synchronization context is smart enough to schedule the continuation on the message-pump thread as well.

Whether you go down the `Task` route or not, this strategy means that you can safely add more operands from an observable event without re-entering any locks.

Comment: I should check how it works with an AddAsync() method but I like this solution! Consumers will await if they need to be sure what they added is available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the same issue but when dealing with relatively small amounts of data (2k-3k entries), I have used the below code to facilitate cross thread read/write access to collections bound to UI. This code originally found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/have-worker-thread-update-observablecollection-that-is-bound-to-a.aspx).

```cs
public class BaseObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
  // Constructors
  public BaseObservableCollection() : base() { }
  public BaseObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items) : base(items) { }
  public BaseObservableCollection(List<T> items) : base(items) { }

  // Evnet
  public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

  // Event Handler
  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    // Be nice - use BlockReentrancy like MSDN said
    using (BlockReentrancy())
    {
      if (CollectionChanged != null)
      {
        // Walk thru invocation list
        foreach (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler in CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
        {
          DispatcherObject dispatcherObject = handler.Target as DispatcherObject;

          // If the subscriber is a DispatcherObject and different thread
          if (dispatcherObject != null && dispatcherObject.CheckAccess() == false)
          {
            // Invoke handler in the target dispatcher's thread
            dispatcherObject.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind, handler, this, e);
          }
          else
          {
            // Execute handler as is
            handler(this, e);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have also used the code below (which inherits from the above code) to support raising the `CollectionChanged` event when items inside the collection raise the `PropertyChanged`.

```
public class BaseViewableCollection<T> : BaseObservableCollection<T>
  where T : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  // Constructors
  public BaseViewableCollection() : base() { }
  public BaseViewableCollection(IEnumerable<T> items) : base(items) { }
  public BaseViewableCollection(List<T> items) : base(items) { }

  // Event Handlers
  private void ItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var arg = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, sender, sender);
    base.OnCollectionChanged(arg);
  }

  protected override void ClearItems()
  {
    foreach (T item in Items) { if (item != null) { item.PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged; } }
    base.ClearItems();
  }

  protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
  {
    if (item != null) { item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged; }
    base.InsertItem(index, item);
  }

  protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
  {
    if (Items[index] != null) { Items[index].PropertyChanged -= ItemPropertyChanged; }
    base.RemoveItem(index);
  }

  protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
  {
    if (item != null) { item.PropertyChanged += ItemPropertyChanged; }
    base.SetItem(index, item);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Thread Collection Synchronization

Putting a ListBox binding to a **ObservableCollection** , when the data changes , you update the ListBox because INotifyCollectionChanged implemented .
The defect dell'ObservableCollection is that the data can be changed only by the thread that created it.

The **SynchronizedCollection** does not have the problem of Multi-Thread but does not update the ListBox because it is not implemented INotifyCollectionChanged , even if you implement INotifyCollectionChanged , CollectionChanged (this, e) can only be called from the thread that created it .. so it does not work.

**Conclusion**

-If you want a list that is **autoupdated mono-thread** use **ObservableCollection**

-If you want a list that is **not autoupdated but multi-threaded** use **SynchronizedCollection**

-**If you want both, use Framework 4.5**, BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization and ObservableCollection () in this way :

```
/ / Creates the lock object somewhere
private static object _lock = new object () ;
...
/ / Enable the cross acces to this collection elsewhere
BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization ( _persons , _lock )
```

**The Complete Sample**
http://10rem.net/blog/2012/01/20/wpf-45-cross-thread-collection-synchronization-redux

Comment: Thank you, good for reference! Problem is that SyncrhonizedCollection uses a monitor as synchronization mechanism. My _problem_ was to avoid monitors in favor of something more _concurrent_ (like ReadWriterLockSlim) for scenarios with multiple concurrent reads and few writes (actually not directly related to user interface).